# Migration from IBM WebSphere to Tomcat 9, the application uses EJB component and oracle database

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, websphere, ejb

I need help in migrating from IBS WebSphere 8.5 to tomcat 9 version. We use oracle 11g DB. My application uses EJB component as well.
Can you guide me:
1: What is the best technology to replace the EJB components, options like JPA, Hibernate etc?
2: What is the code changes for EJB and database connect, if we want to change the DB from Oracle to PostgreSQL?

Any link or blog or steps will be a great help.

Note: We can not choose tomEE or anything else, the option we have is only tomcat 9.

Comment: 1. Opinion. Unless you provide comprehensive objective criteria. Define "best". 2. Too broad. And too dependent on selection criteria from (1).

Comment: And ... *"Any link or blog or steps will be a great help."* - is asking for an off-site resource recommendation.

Comment: You don't need to replace Hiibernate.  It will work fine with Tomcat 9.  It's just not *part* of it.   And it will work fine with different backend databases.   (But changing too many things at the same time is making the migration more complicated than it needs to be.)

Comment: I'd also consider migration to [OpenLiberty](https://openliberty.io/), which is open source like Tomcat, but is much more compatible with WebSphere, so your migration will be much easier.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.